# EmberJS hasMany relationship length returning 0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have a summoner model

```
TournamentAdmin.Summoner = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  elo: DS.attr('number'),
  team: DS.belongsTo('TournamentAdmin.Team')
});
```

and a Team model

```
TournamentAdmin.Team = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  summoners: DS.hasMany('TournamentAdmin.Summoner')
});
```

The team model works fine but when I try to get the summoner model from the Team model, it returns nothing. A length of 0.

The JSON returned to generate the Team model is 
`{"team":{"id":1,"name":"Anujan","email":"wat@wat.com","summoners":[{"id":1,"name":"Anujan","elo":100}]}}`

I've tried adding the team_id to the json as well.

The template is

```
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <h2>by {{email}}</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="below-the-fold">
    {{summoners.length}}
    {{#each summoner in summoners}}
        please print something
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http response is not the format which ember-data expects for sideloaded data.

Look at http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships how your response should look like.

Maybe there is a way to configure/adapt the RESTAdapter... but i have no clue how

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I managed to fix it with that information and the documentation on Active Model Serializers! Really appreciate your help :)